# Generate designer files in monodevelop for aspx files

Tags: asp.net, monodevelop

I'm having a hard time trying to launch an old ASP.NET website (which was build using Visual Studio I assume) with Monodevelop.

I've create an "empty ASP.NET 2.0 MVC Project" (I also tried with an "empty Web Application) solution and added my files. Unfortunately, there is no designers files in the project and controls created in the Aspx files aren't accessible by the related aspx.cs file.

I assume the file needs an aspx.designer.cs to work properly but I can't figure out how to manually generate it.

I tried to create one empty myself, but didn't regenerate.
I tried to clean the project, rebuild it etc. didn't work.

I looked at aspx files created by Monodevelop which hash a related designer file but couldn't find the difference with mine.

Can someone help me on this one ?

Thanks,
Andréas